# Synthesis using Cationic Hetero-Cope Rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

By searching for the reference of the synthesis below I arrived at an example of Cationic Hetero-Cope Rearrangement, but I can't access the paper. How does it work here, and what happens in the first step of the synthesis (the addition of iBuOH and TsOH at 80 degrees)?

[image]

Comment: I assume the "numbers" correspond to the order of the reaction steps.  The first step forms the beta-keto enol ether.  That and a look at the [abstract](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00196a041)  might make the rest of the sequence understandable. I don't see any Cope reaction involved in the formation of this product, just a Diels-Alder.

Comment: What is reduced by DIBAL-H?

Comment: After 1,4 addition of the vinyl grignard, the DIBAL-H reduces the remaining ketonic carbonyl.

Comment: Strange selectivity. Anyway, when does on OH group eliminate? When BuLi is added (one eq eliminates one OH group, the other deprotonates the second)?

Comment: I'm just guessing that it's when the molecule is heated in the last step.

Comment: Seems more reasonable.

Comment: I see you're a first year undergrad.  Are they covering stuff like this and *trans*-cyclooctene chirality in a class, or are you studying these things on your own?

Comment: I am studying on my own. I find the university pace not so demanding. By the way, this problem is from an organic chemistry competition (to put the numbers that correspond to the order of the reaction steps).

Comment: Impressive!  You ask good questions too.  If you stay with it you may one day find that you have a real gift for chemistry.  Good luck in your studies!

Comment: BTW Marko don't forget that self-answers are highly encouraged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the reaction sequence:
[image]